# Как с помощью phpmailer прикрепить к письму сразу несколько файлов

Tags: php, phpmailer

Есть код phpmailer-a который прикрепляет только один файл к письму:

```
$mailer = "test2015@gmail.com";
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->From = 'test@test.ru';      // от кого //Почта клиента
$mail->FromName = "Картины LP";   // от кого
$mail->IsHTML(true);        // выставляем формат письма HTML
$mail->Subject = $subject;  // тема письма;

if ($_FILES['file2']) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file2']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file2']['name']);
}

$mail->Body = '$message';
$mail->AddAddress($mailer); // кому - адрес, Имя
$mail->Send();
```

в форме стоит мультизагрузка(возможность выбрать сразу несколько файлов). Как изменить данный php код чтобы прикреплял все файлы пришедшие от формы ?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было как-то так чтоли:

```
$mailer = "test2015@gmail.com";
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->From = 'test@test.ru';      // от кого //Почта клиента
        $mail->FromName = "Картины LP";   // от кого
        $mail->IsHTML(true);        // выставляем формат письма HTML
        $mail->Subject = $subject;  // тема письма;
        if (!empty($_FILES['file1']['name'][0])) {
            foreach ($_FILES['file1']['name'] as $key => $value) {
                $out_files[] = array("name"=>$_FILES['file1']['name'][$key], "tmp_name" => $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'][$key]);
            }
            $filesSend = true;
        } else {
            $filesSend = false;    
        }
        if ($filesSend) {
            foreach ($out_files as $k=>$v) {
                $mail->AddAttachment($out_files[$k]['tmp_name'], $out_files[$k]['name']);
            }
        }
        $mail->Body = '$message';
        $mail->AddAddress($mailer); // кому - адрес, Имя
        $mail->Send();
```

и это по крайней мере работает.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_FILES['file_1'])) {  
 if($_FILES['file_1']['error'][0] == 0){  
  $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file_1']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file_1']['name']);  
  } 
 }  
if(isset($_FILES['file_2'])) {  
 if($_FILES['file_2']['error'][0] == 0){  
  $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file_2']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file_2']['name']);  
  } 
 }  
 // И так далее...
```

Comment: аще не то :) Приходит массив файлов с одного input type=file name="file1[ ]".